# javascript fancey popup window external page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, lightbox

I would liek to implement a function to open a pop-up window. The implementation of dialogbox and lightbox has failed me in this instance. The link and content on my page is created through JS and PHP. It creates a table with results, and each result has a link to view all details. I was unable to implement Jquery plugins and am greatfull for any help on this. Here is teh function from which I would like to open a new fancy pop-up -> not browser page or tab !! so the windo.open should be replaced. Any idea ??

```
    function showCourse(code)
{
    //alert(1)
    $.ajax({
        async:false,
        type: "POST",
        url: 'formPostsUser.php?reqtype=getCourse',
        data:'coursecode='+ code,
        success: function(data) 
        {
            window.open (url,"mywindow","menubar=1,resizable=1,width=350,height=250");
        }
    });
```

}

Thanks for any hints
Alex

Answer (score 1):

You cannot insure that it won't be opened into a tab, but most browser recognize pop-ups with the width and height attribute. The window.open should work if the target "mywindow" is already there. Have you tried to target _blank?

[EDIT]
A lightbox effect isn't that difficult to implement. In your success function simply create an empty div that will serve as your lightbox. Then add the received data in the div and show your lightbox using an effect.

```
success: function(data)
{   
    $('body').add('div#lightbox')
             .append(data)
             .animate({width: "350px", height:"250px"}, 1500);
}
```

Simply hide by default the lightbox div then change its style using the animate function or any other effect jQuery has. And you'll also have to style the div to be located where you want (absolute/static).

Comment: no success on that one. I dont mind rewriting the whole thing, but something must work for a nice pop-up here !

Comment: Is the popup opening on a blank page? To me the url parameter seems out of scope and it should be taken from the data parameter.

Comment: I was able to open a new browser window, but I need something like lightbos / lightwindow, something that looks clean and opens ontop of the page, a new window is not accaptable ! and any plugins i tried dont work for me ! If I'd know how to implement lightbos jquery or so, directly in this function being called I'd be very happy !!

Comment: Had a typo. This is a really small sample. IMHO You should really read a bit of the jQuery doc, you'll end up writing better code that'll fit exactly what you need. Post it back if you need help :)

Comment: ok no error, but funny enough it just shifts my page to the left, instead of opening a popup !? any further hints ? I feel like this is the type of solution to get what I am looking for

Comment: sorry, i am really grap with this stuff aatm, and am just frustrated cos I dont have much time to get this done ! And am clueless about JS and jquery !

Comment: What happens now is, it prints the new page, at the bottom of my current content, instead of opening a pop-up window

Comment: It will add stuff to your page. To have to style it so it appears to be a modal. Modal windows are simply a div positioned above everything. Try adding #lightbox { position: absolute; margin: 0 auto; top: 100px; } to your CSS and see.

Comment: it changes where it print the result, instead of bottom, it is at top, but page is still shifting to the left, and no pop-up, it just goes over my page